The connection between determinants and eigenvalues
I'm trying to prove the following proposition:

Let $A\in \operatorname{Mat}_n\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ be a matrix with no real eigenvalues.
Then $\det\left(A\right)>0$

I know how to prove it when $n=2$ : when you try to find the eigenvalues, you get a quadratic equation, and when you use the properties of the discriminant the desired result follows quickly. I'm stuck in the general case, however.
It is clear why $\det\left(A\right) \ne 0$, because otherwise $0$ would be a real eigenvalue. But I don't understand why the determinant can't be negative. I would be glad for a hint or a nudge in the right direction - is there anything I'm missing?
Thanks ahead.

Hints: The determinant is the product of eigenvalues. Do eigenvalues come in conjugate pairs in the case of a matrix with real entries? What's a complex number times its conjugate?

This was a hint, not a real question.

In a review there are only a few options to consider. Perhaps hints should start with "Hint(s):".

I thought since the OP asked for a hint, I would not need to label a hint as such. I will edit it regardless.

Having no real eigenvalues tells you that $\det\big(A + \lambda  I \big)\neq 0$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.
This implies that
$\det\Big((1-\tau) A +\tau I  \Big)\neq 0$
for $\tau \in [0,1]$.  Thus $A\in GL_n(\mathbb R)$ is path connected to the identity so $\det\big(A\big)\gt 0$ by Intermediate Value Theroem.

This is a very funny argument, I like that it somehow manages to avoid mentioning conjugation at all.

@QiaochuYuan, I like this argument, too. It is essentially the same as that given by e.g. Tob Ernack but it  avoids  having to deal with $\lambda\to\infty$ by reparameterizing.

This uses some facts from abstract algebra. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ has no real roots. A real polynomial, that has no real roots has only complex roots. Complex roots, however, always appear in pairs $a\pm ib.$ But if both are eigenvalues then their product is $a^2+b^2>0.$ As this holds for all eigenvalues, you can nowhere get negative.

I think you mean "Complex roots of a real polynomial appear in pairs".

I mean all roots since there are no real roots by assumption. That leaves only complex roots.

Sure; I am saying that "Complex roots always appear in pairs" - this is a feature of real polynomials, and I am suggesting you call that out, instead of making the dependency indirect (as it is in your answer)

Yes. It is the same as in the quadratic case. If you have a (monic) real polynomial it splits into linear and quadratic factors: $p(x)=(x-a_1)\ldots (x_a_k)(x^2+b_1x+c_1)\ldots (x^2+b_lx+c_l)$ The linear factors belong to real roots (zeros of $p(x))$ which we do not have here and the quadratic factors belong to complex roots of the form $a\pm i b.$ The reason for it is finally the dimension of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ which is two, hence quadratic factors and complex conjugate zeros, namely $-(b_j/2) \pm (1/2)\sqrt{b_j^2- 4c_j}$ and the term under the root is negative (no real roots!).

The eigenvalues of $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ are precisely the roots of
$$p(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I_n - A) = \lambda^n \det\left(I_n - \frac{1}{\lambda}A\right)$$
As $|\lambda| \to \infty$, we have $\frac{1}{\lambda}A \to 0$ (in the sense of the Frobenius metric on $M_n(\mathbb{R})$) so $\det\left(I_n - \frac{1}{\lambda}A\right) \to 1$. This means that $p(\lambda) \sim \lambda^n$, and in particular $p(\lambda) \gt 0$ for some $\lambda \gt 0$.
If $n$ is odd, then $p(\lambda) \lt 0$ for some $\lambda \lt 0$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, this means $p$ has a real root.
Also if $p(0) \leq 0$ then $p$ has a real root again by the Intermediate Value Theorem.
So if $A$ has no real eigenvalues, we must have $n$ even and $p(0) \gt 0$.
Now $p(0) = \det(-A) = (-1)^n \det(A)$, so this means $(-1)^n \det(A) \gt 0$. But $n$ is even so this means $\det(A) \gt 0$.


The characteristic polynomial $f$ of $A$ is of the form $\lambda^n + p(\lambda)$, where $p$ is a polynomial of degree $\le n-1$. Therefore $\lim_{\lambda \to\infty} f(\lambda) = \infty$.

By assumption $f$ does not vanish on the real line, therefore it is strictly positive on the real line.

This implies $n$ is even (why?).

Next, what is the value of the characteristic polynomial at $\lambda =0$?



@PaulSinclair Then I deleted mine too.
